# mysql count user referral using username | got error

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted the page to show a value

Im having a problem in coding it

```
 <?php  
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM users where reffered = ".$row['username']."");  
   if($result === FALSE) {
     die(mysql_error());
 }
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
 {
    echo  $row['refcount'];
 }
 ?>
```

sample table:

```
username |  reffered
  ace          you
  bin          ace
  cat          ace
  qqqq         ace
```

it should show the value **3**
on the *php*

since ***ace*** referred **3** ***bin*** , ***cat*** and ***qqqq***

Error in this line

```
 Unknown column 'qqqq' in 'where clause'
```

qqqq is username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alias to count and then to print it as follow

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM referred where ref_id = 'user_id'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{
    echo  $row['refcount'];
}
```

Comment: You welcome man, if you feel the answer was correct don't forget to accept it to help people in the future with similar problems.

Comment: `<?php  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM reffered where ref_id = 'username'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{
    echo  $row['refcount'];
}
?>  `

that just show 0 even if it should show 2

Comment: Is the word username you are looking for or username is supposed to be a variable? ($username)

Comment: So you should try "SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM referred where referred LIKE 'ace'"

Comment: now Im confused again
`<?php
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM reffered where refcount = $username ");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
{
    echo  $row['refcount'];
}
  
   ?>`


I just wanted it to show a value on how many users that the one logged in has referred

Comment: So your query should be "SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM referred where referred = '$username'" note that i used referred column since ace was referred two times for bin and cat

Comment: Im having an error on this lines `$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM reffered where reffered = '$username'");  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  `

Notice: Undefined variable
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: Is $username empty? Did you set a value for it?

Comment: that's the whole script tho there is a 
`<?php echo $row['username']; ?>`

on the upper part of the page and it does show the username

Comment: "SELECT COUNT(*) as refcount FROM referred where referred = '".$row['username']."'"

Comment: got this warning
`Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in`
 in this line
`while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: added `if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());`

then it gave me an error

` Unknown column 'qqqq' in 'where clause' `

@Fabio

Comment: Where does qqq come from?

Comment: You dindn't escpae your value with quotes